# Dataframe conditional column subtract until zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

This is different than the usual 'subtract until 0' questions on here as it is conditional on another column. This question is about creating that conditional column.

This dataframe consists of three columns.

**Column 'quantity'** tells you how much to add/subtract.

**Column 'in'** tells you when to subtract.

**Column 'cumulative_in'** tells you how much you have.

```
+----------+----+---------------+
| quantity | in | cumulative_in |
+----------+----+---------------+
|        5 |  0 |               |
|        1 |  0 |               |
|        3 |  1 |             3 |
|        4 |  1 |             7 |
|        2 |  1 |             9 |
|        1 |  0 |               |
|        1 |  0 |               |
|        3 |  0 |               |
|        1 | -1 |               |
|        2 |  0 |               |
|        1 |  0 |               |
|        2 |  0 |               |
|        3 |  0 |               |
|        3 |  0 |               |
|        1 |  0 |               |
|        3 |  0 |               |
+----------+----+---------------+
```

Whenever **column 'in'** equals -1, starting from next row I want to create a **column 'out'** (0/1) that tells it to keep subtracting until 'cumulative_in' reaches 0. Doing it by hand,

**Column 'out'** tells you when to keep subtracting.

**Column 'cumulative_subtracted'** tells you how much you have already subtracted.

I subtract column 'cumulative_in' by 'cumulative_subtracted' until it reaches 0, the output looks something like this:

```
+----------+----+---------------+-----+-----------------------+
| quantity | in | cumulative_in | out | cumulative_subtracted |
+----------+----+---------------+-----+-----------------------+
|        5 |  0 |               |     |                       |
|        1 |  0 |               |     |                       |
|        3 |  1 |             3 |     |                       |
|        4 |  1 |             7 |     |                       |
|        2 |  1 |             9 |     |                       |
|        1 |  0 |               |     |                       |
|        1 |  0 |               |     |                       |
|        3 |  0 |               |     |                       |
|        1 | -1 |               |     |                       |
|        2 |  0 |             7 |   1 |                     2 |
|        1 |  0 |             6 |   1 |                     3 |
|        2 |  0 |             4 |   1 |                     5 |
|        3 |  0 |             1 |   1 |                     8 |
|        3 |  0 |             0 |   1 |                     9 |
|        1 |  0 |               |     |                       |
|        3 |  0 |               |     |                       |
+----------+----+---------------+-----+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Am I correct that this could only happen once in the dataframe, even if you had many more rows? Since 'cumulative_in' is now   0  ?

Comment: could you have more sucessive `in` equal to 1 and more `in` equal to -1 ?

Comment: Also, could you input your dataframe in a more friendly format? pd.DataFrame(data, column, index)?

Comment: What happens when the 'in' column has a 1 but the 'cumulative_in'  (while being in a subtracting phase) has not yet reached zero?

Comment: @run-out This happens multiple times across the dataframe...'cumulative_in' builds up then has to be subtracted to 0 again, whenever 'in' equals -1

Comment: @Frenchy There will only be one '-1' at some point after each sequence of '1's to tell it to deplete the 'cumulative_in' to 0

Comment: @nocibambi there will only be single '-1' after a series of '1's then repeat....so a typical sequence would be 0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,-1,0,0,0,0....

Comment: Do the 'cumulative_in' have to deplete to zero, or can it be still positive when the next -1 arrives?

Comment: @nocibambi they have to go to zero, my aim here is to create a column 'out' (which is trigged by a -1 on 'in') to tell it how many rows it has to deplete before it hits 0

Comment: Does cumulative subtracted keep accumulating or reset after down to zero?

Comment: @run-out it resets, after down to zero it is all np.nan till the next sequence where it starts again

Comment: Cool the solution I just posted works that way. :)

Comment: @Wen-Ben could you use your considerable skills to see if there might be a vectorized solution to this problem? I've posted a loop solution and OP is going to post an iterrows, but I would be interested if you can see a vectorized solution. I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a vector solution to this. I would love to see one. However, the problem is not that hard when going through row by row. I hope your dataframe is not too big!!

First set up the data.

```
data = {
    "quantity": [
        5,1,3,4,2,1,1,3,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,3
    ], 
    "in":[
        0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    ], 
    "cumulative_in":  [
        np.NaN,np.NaN,3,7,9,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN
    ]

}
```

Then set up the dataframe and extra columns. I used np.NaN for the 'out' but 0 was easier for 'cumulative_subtracted'

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['out'] = np.NaN
df['cumulative_subtracted'] = 0
```

Set the initial variables

```
last_in = 0.
reduce = False
```

Go through the dataframe row by row, unfortunately.

```
for i in df.index:
    # check if necessary to adjust last_in value.
    if ~np.isnan(df.at[i, "cumulative_in"]) and reduce == False:
        last_in = df.at[i, "cumulative_in"]
    # check if -1 and change reduce to true
    elif df.at[i, "in"] == -1:
        reduce = True
    # check if reduce true, the implement reductions
    elif reduce == True:
        df.at[i, "out"] = 1
        if df.at[i, "quantity"] <= last_in:
            last_in -= df.at[i, "quantity"]
            df.at[i, "cumulative_in"] = last_in
            df.at[i, "cumulative_subtracted"] = (
                df.at[i - 1, "cumulative_subtracted"] + df.at[i, "quantity"]
            )
        elif df.at[i, "quantity"] > last_in:
            df.at[i, "cumulative_in"] = 0
            df.at[i, "cumulative_subtracted"] = (
                df.at[i - 1, "cumulative_subtracted"] + last_in
            )
            last_in = 0
            reduce = False
```

This works for the data given, and hopefully for all your dataset.

print(df)

```
    quantity  in  cumulative_in  out  cumulative_subtracted
0          5   0            NaN  NaN                      0
1          1   0            NaN  NaN                      0
2          3   1            3.0  NaN                      0
3          4   1            7.0  NaN                      0
4          2   1            9.0  NaN                      0
5          1   0            NaN  NaN                      0
6          1   0            NaN  NaN                      0
7          3   0            NaN  NaN                      0
8          1  -1            NaN  NaN                      0
9          2   0            7.0  1.0                      2
10         1   0            6.0  1.0                      3
11         2   0            4.0  1.0                      5
12         3   0            1.0  1.0                      8
13         3   0            0.0  1.0                      9
14         1   0            NaN  NaN                      0
15         3   0            NaN  NaN                      0
```

Comment: Thank you, I also found another way to run this sequence using df.iterrows(). Will post solution in future

Comment: Cool. When you do the iterrows() solution, could you do a quick speed check against what I posted? I'm reading conflicting information about how fast the two would perform. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if anyone reading this can come up with a vectorized solution to this question, I would love to see it. Mayby @coldspeed ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear for me what happens when the quantity to subtract has not yet reached zero and you have another '1' in the 'in' column.

Yet, here is a rough solution for a simple case:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size = 20

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "quantity": np.random.randint(1, 6, size),
        "in": np.full(size, np.nan),
    }
)

# These are just to place a random 1 and -1 into 'in', not important
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.iloc[:size//3, :].index, 1), 'in'] = 1
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.iloc[size//3:size//2, :].index, 1), 'in'] = -1
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.iloc[size//2:, :].index, 1), 'in'] = 1

# Fill up with 1/-1 values the missing values after each entry up to the
# next 1/-1 entry.
df.loc[:, 'in'] = df['in'].fillna(method='ffill')

# Calculates the cumulative sum with a negative value for subtractions
df["cum_in"] = (df["quantity"] * df['in']).cumsum()

# Subtraction indicator and cumulative column
df['out'] = (df['in'] == -1).astype(int)
df["cumulative_subtracted"] = df.loc[df['in'] == -1, 'quantity'].cumsum()

# Remove values when the 'cum_in' turns to negative
df.loc[
    df["cum_in"] < 0 , ["in", "cum_in", "out", "cumulative_subtracted"]
] = np.NaN


print(df)
```

Comment: Let's assume that after a series of '1's in 'in', there won't be anymore '1's, the next will be a '-1' which will deplete the 'cumulative_in' to 0. Then at some point when there is '1' the 'cumulative_in' builds up again and then '-1' appears causing it to deplete again.

Comment: In its current form, actually, the code almost works in this case. Only when it depletes to zero, it 'remembers' the negative value. So it will not start the next 'cumulative_in' build up from 0 but from that negative number...